# Possible for git to commit automatically when file changes?

Tags: git, bash, shell, photoshop

I'm experimenting with new ways of tracking changes to my Photoshop files when I design and I'd like to know; is it possible to create a script which automatically creates a commit when a change to a file is made (saved).

I use tools like [Pixelapse](http://www.pixelapse.com/) however there are some drawbacks, and one of them is reverting back to previous versions can be a pain because you need to load the website.

Everytime I save my my changes in Photoshop, I'd like git to create a commit.

Having this happen automatically I'm sure will produce some undesirable effects like massive file sizes however I'm open to other suggestions.

**Update:** By the way I'm using Mac OS X if that helps.

Comment: Git can't do it by itself, but depending on operating system you should be able to create a daemon that does that, for example, with OSX you could write a shell script that does the commit and set it up in launchd.

Comment: You should say whether you're on OS X or Windows (I'm assuming it's the former).

Comment: Hi thanks for the comments. I'm using OS X. Are there any resources you would recommend for creating a shell script of this nature? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the inotify-tools is an option.

I don't know if they exist under MacOS X too. A Linux user would install it with `yum install inotify-tools` (RedHat) or `aptitude install inotify-tools` (Debian/Ubuntu).

You could then use `inotifywait`:

```
while [ true ]; do
  inotifywait -e modify test >/dev/null 2>&1
  echo "Do something"
done
```

To bring it into background, wrap it this way:

```
{ while [ true ]; do inotifywait -e modify test >/dev/null 2>&1 ; echo "Do something" ; done }& echo $! > ~/inotitfy.something.pid
```

It will endlessly loop and run `inotifywait` which will exit if the `-e` event occurs and then run `echo` in this example. After creating a background process through `&`. The backgrounded process ID will be piped into `~/inotitfy.something.pid`.

Stop it by killing the process this way:

```
kill -15 `echo ~/inotitfy.something.pid`
```

You could also put the first variant into a [screen](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-screen-command-howto.html).

Note that there might be a `inotifyexec` too (as on Debian Squeeze), but didn't worked for me all time and is not  available on all distributions (so I always use my home-made approach).

Comment: @Sevenupcan Please note that when automatically committing something you are not able to describe the change though a commit message.

Further, committing Photoshop files (on every save) might result in extreme disk space consumption.

If I remember correctly, there's a Photoshop plugin that tracks all your changes and provides you with someting like a timeline. Maybe this works more effective. I didn't find it quickly - you might try searching for it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think a similar tool does exist on MacOS, hopefully I can find something similar. The tool you are thinking of is called Timeline from PixelNovel. It does do what you describe but I'm looking to create a bespoke service. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a shell loop to check if the file hash changed since last time and commit if it did. You can add a sleep in the loop, and use the time stamp as the commit message.

Personally I'd say this is a bit pointless because you should commit useful snapshots, not all of them.

Comment: I understand where you're coming from. For me the action of saving in Photoshop is a different state of mind than any other app I use, so even the smallest change is significant to me. I plan to have a method of setting milestones to highlight particular versions.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something similar, and based on [try-catch-finally](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1078886/try-catch-finally)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14059002/801553) I came up with this:

```
while git ls-files | inotifywait -q  -e modify --fromfile -; do 
  …something… (in your case probably git-commit)
done
```

This has the advantage that only files under version control are watched. Furthermore, since you're most of the time inside the `inotifywait`, it is easier to kill (if you kill the `inotitfywait` it exits “abnormally” and the `while` exits).

You could also think about other events, especially `move` and `move_self` and possibly `create` and `create_self` (then you might want to use some options on `git ls-files` as well).